# Is There DropDown look a like text container

Tags: c#, winforms

i am looking for a text container.

something that will look like this:
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader-faq
or any thing similar (design not really matters).

is there anything like that? i want to create a suitable way to show imformation about my program, "faq" and change log. but designing the whole winform or making many winforms is just too much work and inefficient.

Comment: `designing the whole winform or making many winforms is just too much work and inefficient` - **Yes.** That's why it is highly recommendable that you use WPF instead of winforms for ALL .Net Windows UI requirements.

Comment: @HighCore I am aware of WPF.
im learning software in school and we learn c#. I tried once to learn how to use WPF but it looked like too much work, its not that im lazy i just have too much school work beside programming which leaves me no time to learn it

Comment: no, WPF is not "too much work", it's actually way easier than winforms because it actually has features (as opposed to winforms which doesn't support anything). What you asked about here can be done in WPF with a simple `ItemsControl` consisting of some `Expander`s and some text. You could even easily create the expanding animation, something that would take years of horrible hacks in winforms.

Comment: @HighCore maybe WPF is not too much work, but again, i dont have much time to learn it... when i look at C# i understand it, and i dont know too much about it.
 thanks for trying to help.
it would be nice if you'll give me an example for what is possible to do with wpf, or something known that has been done.

does WPF has anything like c#?

Comment: You use C# in WPF too. The oposites are WPF and Winforms

Comment: @AlejandrodelRío My guess is that XAML has a higher learning curve.

Comment: @D Stanley Of corse! I have your same issue. Look at my answer, it may be usefull to you and it uses winforms ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798031). It surely helps. You can put panels inside that contains all your controlls. It can be horizontal or vertical. You can also add a button to change its size percentage.